# Redirect controller methods in HTTPS Protocol in Playframework

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, playframework-1.x

We use Play framework 1.2.x.

We use Amazon ELB to handle SSL. So a request from browser to Amazon ELB it https. From Amazon ELB to Play its http.

We use to redirect one controller method to another. So when we do redirection Play always make http request  when we do redirection by calling another controller method rather than https as it received http request only. But I would like to specify the protocol when we do redirection from one Controller method to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the baseUrl property in your application.conf to something like the following:

```
baseUrl=https://myserver.com/myapp
```

Answer (score 2):

Please include that code in your `application.conf`:

```
application.baseUrl=https://example.com/
XForwardedSupport=all
XForwardedProto=https
application.session.httpOnly=true
application.session.secure=true
```

My application include all above, and it has run correctly for 2 years.

Comment: The XForwardedSupport=all worked for me without any other configuration.  I'm not sure why it it works with http without the XForwardedSupport, but fails with https.

Comment: The XForwardedProto=https only use when you have a reverse proxy (load balancer), that take control with HTTPS and then communicate with web server with HTTP. If you don't have a reverse proxy to control HTTPS, you can remove that line. But I think you can include without risk. :)

Comment: In my case the proxy (ELB) terminating HTTPS includes the X-Forwarded-Proto as HTTPS which play is correctly detecting.

Comment: Ah, that's right. The XForwardedProto is only useful when ELB didn't forward HTTPS to play.